# How to write ACE_Tstring to file in c++

Tags: c++, file, utf, ace

I'm using windows OS and trying to write `ACE_Tstring` that contains multiple languages sentence(by Unicode) to a file using `ACE_OS::write()`.

But the result I'm getting in the file is unpredictable characters(gibberish text).

This is my code implemented :

```
ACE_Tstring *str = new ACE_Tstring(L"مرحبا привет świecie Hello")
ACE_HANDL hFile = ACE_OS::open(L"myfile", _O_WRONLY);

ACE_OS::write(hFile, str, 1048);
wprintf(L"%ls",str->c_str());
```

As you can see I also print the string to the screen, and on screen I get the characters "????" where any character accept for English characters appear.

Written Text

> مرحبا привет świecie Hello

Result on Screen :

> ?????? ????? ??????? Hello

What am I missing and what is wrong with my code?

Comment: It seems that `c_str()` converts your string to plain ACSII `char`s, so you get rubbish everywhere but English

Answer (score 0):

ACE_TString is a typedef for ACE_CString when ACE_USES_WCHAR is not set. Try using ACE_WString if you need to force it to wide-chars.